# Jersey client doesn't redirect properly on 301 response (after PATCH)

Tags: http, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-client

I use a Jersey client to make a request to an API to change the ID of a resource, using the PATCH method:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient()
    .property(HttpUrlConnectorProvider.SET_METHOD_WORKAROUND, true); // To allow PATCH
...
// Setting uri, path, accessToken and entity used below
...
WebTarget target = client.target(uri).path(path);
Response response = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, BEARER + accessToken)
    .method("PATCH", entity);
```

I see in Fiddler that the ID is changed successfully: a "301 Moved Permanently" response with a Location header is returned, the Location header contains the URL with the new ID.
Then again in Fiddler I see that the Jersey client calls the URL from the Location header, right after the first request, but using the PATCH method again...
Shouldn't it make the request to the URL in the Location header using GET since the response code was 301?

Thanks.